# ImageView Center in position with ScaleType Matrix

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scale

I am using Zoom effect with ImageView so I need to use scaletype=matrix. Now, I want to set Center position to ImageView but I am not able to set it.
Please help me regarding this.
**layout.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgdesc"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_answer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you got any solution ?please share with us

Answer (score 1):

try this to your `ImageView`

```
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: @JeetenParmar change  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and try

Comment: I am scaling Image so I cant use anyone expect matrix.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: I am scaling Image so all these will not work by replacing it with matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Under `android:scaleType="matrix"` circumstance, the only way I found is to use Matrix to set ImageView position, use the following code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postTranslate(screen_width/2, screen_height/2);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the sameproblem. Eventually I Gave up for using Matrix and replaced it with this:

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = desiredHeight;
params.width = desiredWid;
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this may help you

Comment: This will work for sure, but then `ImageView` sets its boundary and so It wont allow user to zoom Image outside of its boundary.