# How to center imageView with matrix scaletype?

Tags: android, imageview, position, zooming, scaletype

I'm using **Android Studio** to display an **imageView**. I'm using pinch zoom to interact with my ImageView.

**Code:**

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scale = scale * detector.getScaleFactor();
        scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5f));
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```

Zoom is fine, but problem is the position of imageview, it's stuck in left upper corner. Tried layout changes but nothing to do. After some reseaches, I've seen these links in the forum [ImageView Center in position with ScaleType Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755102/imageview-center-in-position-with-scaletype-matrix) and [Center the image in ImageView after zoom-pinch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687577/center-the-image-in-imageview-after-zoom-pinch), but these solutions aren't working, I've also checked the links given inside.

Help would be appreciated,

Thanks !

**EDIT**: Added the piece of code on how I get my ImageView

```
Picasso.with(this).load(url).resize(350, 330).centerInside().into(imageView);
```

**onCreate Code**

[image: onCreate]

**ScaleListner Class and Gesture Code**

[image: listener]

Comment: read `Matrix#setScale` documentetion (and `preScale` / `postScale`)

Comment: I've done this, and it didn't help me @pskink

Comment: well,  dump your `Matrix` anytime you change it by using `Log.d` method

Comment: Do you have an example please ? @pskink

Comment: example? example of what?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of a code that would place the imageview in center of layout @pskink please ?

Comment: have you seen the `Matrix` after calling `setScale`?

Comment: @pskink yes this line:  imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
    Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageView, new Callback.EmptyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
            // TODO: check that d isn't null

            RectF imageRectF = new RectF(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            RectF viewRectF = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
            matrix.setRectToRect(imageRectF, viewRectF, ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
    });
```

**Edit 2:**

How to center the image like `CENTER_INSIDE` but using matrix:

First we need a rectangle with the image dimensions:

```
    Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
    // TODO: check that d isn't null

    RectF imageRectF = new RectF(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Next you need a rectangle with the view dimensions:

```
    RectF viewRectF = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
```

Now we run a method on matrix that will center the image in the view:

```
    matrix.setRectToRect(imageRectF, viewRectF, ScaleToFit.CENTER);
```

What this does is set up the matrix so that the first rectangle will transform to the second rectangle.  `ScaleToFit.CENTER` will preserve the aspect ratio and have the same effect as scale type `CENTER_INSIDE`.

So if you call

```
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

at this point, you will have a centered image.

---

**Edit:** I think you are almost there.

Your matrix will undo the image centering that Picasso did, so you need to put in a translation to center the image before you scale it.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
        // if d is null, then Picasso hasn't loaded the image yet

        float offsetX = (imageView.getWidth() - d.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2F;
        float offsetY = (imageView.getHeight() - d.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2F;

        float centerX = imageView.getWidth() / 2F;
        float centerY = imageView.getHeight() / 2F;

        // note that these offset and center values don't change with the scaling, 
        // so you can calculate them somewhere else and then use them here.

        scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5f));

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.preTranslate(offsetX, offsetY);

        imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
```

---

You are using `setScale(float sx, float sy)`.  There is another version, `setScale(float sx, float sy, float px, float py)` where px,py is a *pivot point*.

So if you want to center your image, determine the center of your view and use the x,y value as the pivot point.

You will also want to center the image inside the view, so you will need to move the image first before you scale.

```
    float offsetX = (imageView.getWidth() - bitmap.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2F;
    float offsetY = (imageView.getHeight() - bitmap.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2F;

    float centerX = imageView.getWidth() / 2F;
    float centerY = imageView.getHeight() / 2F;

    matrix.setScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
    matrix.preTranslate(offsetX, offsetY);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'm trying it as soon as I can !

Comment: Having some errors with variables view, image (which i tried to replace), and it doesn't know matrix.preTransform

Comment: Should have been `preTranslate`, updated my answer. You can leave off the `preTranslate` method just to see the image zoom without being stuck in the upper left hand corner.  But I'm betting your image isn't centered, so you will need a translation in there somewhere to center the image in the view.

Comment: `view` should have been `imageView`.  You didn't include any code for how you are getting the actual bitmap, so I just called it `bitmap`.  The main point is that you will need the dimensions of the bitmap as well as the dimensions of the `ImageView` in order to center the bitmap so the scaling looks right.

Comment: I updated my code, in fact, I'm using Picasso with a URL passed from an other activity to populate my imageview, thanks for your help ! Im not using directly a bitmap, how can I do it ?

Comment: Ah. So you don't need the `preTranslate` as Picasso is doing the centering for you.  So does adding the pivot point to the scaling make it work?

Comment: My imageview is still in the left upper corner, but when I zoom it gets out of the view, code updated

Comment: Okay, I think I know what's going on. So Picasso is centering the image, but as soon as you apply the matrix to the `ImageView`, it goes back to the upper left corner?

Comment: Yes, I can't see it that much but yes it is.

Comment: First of all thank you for this huge help, yes I'm almost there. Here is the situation with the updated answer. I have touched the imageview, its beginning position is in the upper left corner, then when I zoom, it places itself in the center of the view and stays there. Tried to make it centered at launch of activity but failed. Any idea ? Sorry for bothering

Comment: So once you start zooming everything's okay but the image is in wrong place to start?

Comment: This is exactly what's happening yes

Comment: Sorry still not working, I updated my screeshot class to show you

Comment: That second bit of code was not for the `onScale` method.  You said the image was in the wrong place to start.  Once the image has been loaded, you can use that code to center the image when you are not scaling.

Comment: My bad, I've put it in my onCreate method, so I passed the Drawable d declaration out of scope from my ScaleListener class, so I can use it in onCreate and onScale method. I have a NullPointerException, which I expected  --> "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference". But I don't really know what to put from here

Comment: No, it wouldn't be `onCreate`.  Earlier you said, "I have touched the imageview, its beginning position is in the upper left corner".  I'm trying to understand how Picasso is centering the image, yet the image is getting reset to (0,0) before you zoom it.  Are you calling `imageView.setImageMatrix()` anywhere else? If so, you should post that section of code.  Are you also using a `GestureDetector`?   That listener code should be posted as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112765/discussion-between-kris-larson-and-jay).

Comment: Thanks for you help, it is the perfect solution with Picasso ! Accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using Glide. I have set `scaleType` to `matrix` in the XML, and the initial loaded image appears with the auto top left zoomed. I change the image loading to view with Glide. It solved the issue. For more insight, check Glide's basic image-loading functions.

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(receivedUri)
     .into(imageView)
```